# Ionic 3 and firebase storage

Tags: cordova, firebase, ionic3

There is a situation where I have some audios on firebase storage and need to download on phone locals memory so when I start application it should check if there is any audio in local memory if exists it plays otherwise download it from firebase storage.

Any one can help me this ionic 3 and firebase ?

I have this connectivity

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.4/firebase.js"></script>
<script >
var config = {
apiKey: "AIzaSyAg6dBk2BJ-DlFHm0f0G-9XpIcjb-Zl7DY",
authDomain: "helloworld-4e6e6.firebaseapp.com",
databaseURL: "https://helloworld-4e6e6.firebaseio.com",
projectId: "helloworld-4e6e6",
storageBucket: "helloworld-4e6e6.appspot.com",
messagingSenderId: "386944915967"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>
```

here is my.ts file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AboutPage } from '../about';
import { FileTransfer, FileUploadOptions, FileTransferObject } from '@ionic- 
native/file-transfer';
import { NativeAudio } from '@ionic-native/native-audio';

@Component({
   selector: 'page-home',
   templateUrl: 'home.html'
 })
 export class HomePage {
 bleep = new Audio();
   constructor() {
}
 download() {
     const url = 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/helloworld- 
 4e6e6.appspot.com/o/audio%2Fp10_1.mp3?alt=media&token=12bf3400-17a7-4cf9- 
 b862-973707a3164e';
      fileTransfer.download(url, this.file.dataDirectory + 
 'test.mp3').then((entry) => {
       console.log('download complete: ' + entry.toURL());
     }, (error) => {
          console.log('Error during download: '+error);
      });
   }


 wajid()
 {

 const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();
 this.download();
 this.nativeAudio.preloadSimple('uniqueId1', this.file.dataDirectory + 
 'test.mp3').then((res) => {
         console.log('Mp3 ready');
     }, (error) => {
         console.log("Some error during load the audio "+error);
      });

      this.nativeAudio.play('uniqueId1').then((onSuccess)=>{
          console.log('Mp3 reproduced ok');
      }, (onError)=>{
          console.log("Some error during reproduce of the audio "+onError);
      });

      // can optionally pass a callback to be called when the file is done 
   playing
      //this.nativeAudio.play('uniqueId1', () => console.log('uniqueId1 is 
  done playing'));


 }
```

here is my html button

```
<div class= "sections" style="width: 18%;" (tap)="wajid()" (press) = "wajidlong5()">
      <div class = "sections" id = "sec1" >
       ﻞَ  
      </div><!--
      --><div class = "sections" id = "sec2" >
         ﻌَ  
      </div><!--
      --><div class = "sections" id = "sec3" >
           ﺟَ  
      </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Not really.... You have to learn more about ionic... It's not so simply.

Comment: @Cristian from where i learn to achieve this i really ned to do this ASAP ! help me dude

Comment: Here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/, look for File Transfer, there you can also check if file already exist

Comment: @Cristian i need to download an audio from firebase storage and then check if already exist it plays from assets otherwise it will download and place that audio in assets folder and then play from assets. Kindly help :)

Comment: You can't put directly in assets. Check FILETRANSFER ionic plugin

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-transfer/

Comment: @Cristian how can i download that audio, firstly ?

Answer (score 0):

To download the audio, by using : [File Transfer](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-transfer/)

```
const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();

import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';

constructor(private file: File) { }

download() {
  const url = 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/helloworld-4e6e6.appspot.com/o/audio%2Fp10_1.mp3?alt=media&token=12bf3400-17a7-4cf9-b862-973707a3164e';
  fileTransfer.download(url, this.file.dataDirectory + 'test.mp3').then((entry) => {
    console.log('download complete: ' + entry.toURL());
  }, (error) => {
    // handle error
  });
}
```

To check if the file is in your folder use this native plugin [File](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file/).

Look on two plugin specifications.

For problem ask here and I ll edit the answer

To play the file you have to use [NATIVE AUDIO](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/native-audio/) . 
SO:

```
this.nativeAudio.preloadSimple('uniqueId1', this.file.dataDirectory + 'test.mp3').then(onSuccess, onError);
```

AND NOW:

```
this.nativeAudio.play('uniqueId1').then(onSuccess, onError);

// can optionally pass a callback to be called when the file is done playing
this.nativeAudio.play('uniqueId1', () => console.log('uniqueId1 is done playing'));
```

Complete code:

```
import { FileTransfer, FileUploadOptions, FileTransferObject } from '@ionic-native/file-transfer';
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';
import { NativeAudio } from '@ionic-native/native-audio';

constructor(private transfer: FileTransfer,private file: File,private nativeAudio: NativeAudio) {
    const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();
    this.download();
    this.nativeAudio.preloadSimple('uniqueId1', this.file.dataDirectory + 'test.mp3').then((res) => {
        console.log('Mp3 ready');
    }, (error) => {
        console.log("Some error during load the audio "+error);
    });

    this.nativeAudio.play('uniqueId1').then((onSuccess)=>{
        console.log('Mp3 reproduced ok');
    }, (onError)=>{
        console.log("Some error during reproduce of the audio "+onError);
    });

    // can optionally pass a callback to be called when the file is done playing
    //this.nativeAudio.play('uniqueId1', () => console.log('uniqueId1 is done playing'));

 }

download() {
    const url = 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/helloworld-4e6e6.appspot.com/o/audio%2Fp10_1.mp3?alt=media&token=12bf3400-17a7-4cf9-b862-973707a3164e';
    fileTransfer.download(url, this.file.dataDirectory + 'test.mp3').then((entry) => {
      console.log('download complete: ' + entry.toURL());
    }, (error) => {
        console.log('Error during download: '+error);
    });
  }
```

Comment: In your page.ts. download() is the function to download the file.  this.file.dataDirectory  is the directory where the file will be downloaded

Comment: do i have to specify the path replacing this.file.dataDirectory or let it be the way it is present btw my file should be downloaded in directory (Desktop\hello\www\assets\sounds)

Comment: my firebase storage audio url is --> https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/helloworld-4e6e6.appspot.com/o/audio%2Fp10_1.mp3?alt=media&token=12bf3400-17a7-4cf9-b862-973707a3164e  

and where i need to download this i.e --> Desktop\hello\www\assets\sounds

can you please edit with these urls

Comment: I put the url, for the path where to save, search on File plugin

Comment: i posted your above code when button clicked so now it should download and how to play downloaded file ?

Comment: sorry cristian im so confused its giving me an error can you edit the post and do it step step ? 
1. Audio is uploaded on firebase storage and url is there 
2. Download that audio from storage and save it in assets folder when button is clicked. Url is there 
3. Then play the downloaded audio from assets and if audio doesnt exists in assets it should download it from firebase storage.

atleast point 1 and 2 can you make it clear for me so that i can achieve it . i shall be very thankful to you.

Comment: When i click a button to call this download function it gives me an error that "cannot read property 'create' of undefined

Comment: help me with this brother even i can pay some amount to achieve this :(

Comment: I explain all steps, to do full code it takes me 1 hour, so i can't. Please ask some specific question and I can answer you .. But i can't write all the code ...

Comment: i pasted your above code and it is giving me error when i click on button to download audio

Comment: Is defined this?  this.file.dataDirectory ... import file

Comment: i did'nt get you

Comment: let me check this now cristian

Comment: i need to download the audio within the app

Comment: i copied your whole code still giving me an error that cannot read property 'create' of undefined.

Comment: i edited my post Cristian now help me with that when i click button it still gives me same error that cannot read property 'create' of undefined

Comment: Your constructor() is empty

Comment: what should be there in constructor ? kindly copy my post, correct it and edit your post. i shall be very thankful to you Cristian.

Comment: constructor(private transfer: FileTransfer,private file: File,private nativeAudio: NativeAudio) {...put all here}